# Unable to run 'keyboard.is_pressed' on Mac

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

Im trying to make a script where every time I press x, it prints y.

When I run the code:

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
    print ("y")
```

The console outputs:

```
   raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

Thanks!

Comment: Error message seems straightforward. Try running it as administrator. Maybe the `keyboard` module needs that in OSX.

Comment: Could you also show us the entire console output? I assume that line of code is only the end of the traceback, and you don't actually have a `raise OSError` in your code.

Comment: Yea, here is the entire error: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 292, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator

Comment: Im not sure how to run as administrator

Comment: Can you edit your question to put in the full traceback? I don't know much about OSX so I can't really help but I'm sure it'll be easier for someone else to answer your question that way.

Answer (score 6):

You can't run a script with virtual keyboard inputs like you regular python file in the macOS terminal due to a security feature.

Let's assume your filename is script.py.

If you type

```
python3 script.py
```

macOS would view this as a security breach as recording keyboard inputs (*like keyboard.is_pressed('x')*) is a typical method for recording someone's password as they type it in on a website, application, etc.

---

To prevent that error, you'd need to run the file as an administrator.

To do so, type:

```
sudo python3 script.py
```

It will ask you for your user's password and then proceed to execute the code.

Comment: This (sudo) resulted in "sh: segmentation fault  sudo python3 pythonstuff.py" on macOS Monterey.

Comment: keyboard is a module for windows and linux (that's what it says while installing it)

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard module registers global key events (they trigger without application focus) and this requires administrator permissions under MacOS.

Comment: Which makes this module pretty much useless ... who would like to run Python code as administrator (or any other code for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to
system settings -> Privacy & Security and find give python access to control your keyboard

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).