# Python Keyboard Module OsError13

Tags: python-3.x, macos, keyboard

I am trying to learn all about python. So naturally I installed some packages (bumpy, pandas, sicpy, and keyboard). I was playing around with the `keyboard` package but I kept getting `OSError 13`. I've seen people have this same problem but no one has given a definite answer on how to fix this.

I looked around on GitHub and stuff. There was a thread on GitHub from 2018 with the same issue but, again there was no definite answer.

Here is the Error Message I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 292, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

Here is the actual program code:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

The error message is in the code. I am also a noob so if this has been answered, if someone could link to that answer. Also: I'm running this with IDLE on Mac OS.

Comment: Error likely has nothing to do with IDLE or whatever IDE.  To be sure, run python in TerminaI with 'python3' and enter 'import terminal' at python's '>>>' prompt. If you do not understand 'run as administrator' search web for 'macOS run as administrator'.  I am pretty sure error happens during the import.  Hence the suggestion to run 'import keyboard' by itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run 'keyboard.is\_pressed' on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940429/unable-to-run-keyboard-is-pressed-on-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Terminal, your code should work with

`sudo python3 your_script.py`