# Is there a way to run code as administrator in visual studio code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have this problem: [Unable to run 'keyboard.is_pressed' on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940429/unable-to-run-keyboard-is-pressed-on-mac)

To fix this, I need to run it as an administrator from the terminal. Is there a way to do this from Visual Studio Code? Thanks

I have now also tried so other things that have been, so far, unsuccessful. These are:

- Launching VS Code as an admin
- changing my launch.json with "sudo": true and some other things the internet said to do
- running the python file as an administrator to see if that gives it the correct "privileges" to be run as admin from the app
- given VS Code access to my documents folder

the requested message, final few lines:

```
Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3' '/Users/wayow/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher' '59853' '--' '/Users/wayow/mystuff/Pythonstuff/test/problemthing.py'
env: illegal option -- a
usage: env [-iv] [-P utilpath] [-S string] [-u name]
           [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
```

Comment: what error you have when you run vscode as admin?

Comment: @gftea no error, but the files aren't run as admin like I want them to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put this in .vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "sudo": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and run your .py file and paste any error messages in your question.

It should open an external terminal.

I tested fine in MacOS Monterey.

**Update**

To get around `env '-a'` issue, open a `Terminal` and run :

1. `mkdir $HOME/bin`
2. Paste following (from `cat ...` including `EOF`) in the `Terminal`, type `Enter` at the end :

```
cat <<'EOF' > $HOME/bin/env
#!/bin/bash
test "$1" = -a && shift
exec /usr/bin/env "$@"
EOF
```

3. `chmod +x "$HOME/bin/env"`
4. `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`
5. `open -a "Visual Studio Code" "python-project-directory"`
6. Run .py file

Comment: When in press f5 to run, it opens the external terminal but doesn't run the program in the terminal. it is filled with a weird message with file directories and stuff. it is too long to fit into a comment.

Comment: Can you put a few lines of messages in your question ?

Comment: yes, i ahve done that. here is a pastebin of the whole thing if you want: https://pastebin.com/DgtH43Hk

Comment: I don't really understand what to do in step 2, could you explain it some more?